# Gatsby - Adding meta tags for SSR using react-head/react-helmet doesn't work on dynamically created pages

Tags: gatsby

I've been researching this problem for a week now and still stumped. I have a website that uses Gatsby with Prismic, and i've got 2 different types of pages: static and dynamically created pages. Static can include pages like homepage, contact us page, about us page, etc. Dynamic can include blog posts, services pages, etc.

I've used react-helmet to inject metadata into the pages, but i've since moved to using react-head. This works on static pages, it's included in the SSR version of the pages - but it doesn't work for dynamic pages. I've also put in a console.log on a Layout component that I use on all of the pages, and on the static pages it shows up on the terminal, but on dynamic pages it doesn't.

My config includes the following plugins:

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-catch-links`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-resolve-src`,
    `gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes`,
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    `gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-prismic-graphql",
      options: {
        repositoryName: "<redacted>",
        linkResolver: () => (post) => `/${post.uid}`,
        omitPrismicScript: true,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `sample`,
        short_name: `sample`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `sample-notext.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
      options: {
        trackingId: "UA-107057776-1",
        head: true,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-iltorb",
      options: {
        extensions: ["css", "html", "js", "svg", "png", "ttf"],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-preact`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-html-minifier`,
      options: {
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeComments: true,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-html-attributes",
      options: {
        lang: "en",
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-nprogress`,
      options: {
        color: "#dd8d83",
        showSpinner: false,
        minimum: 0.4,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-react-head`,
  ],
```

Pages (both dynamic and static) generally look like this:

```
<Layout
    meta={{
        title: `${post.post_title[0].text} | Not Just a Box Events`,
        description: meta.description,
        image: blog.page_hero_image.url,
    }}
>
    {children}
</Layout>
```

and Layout is this:

```
<LayoutContainer className="div">
    <div className="Layout">
        <header>
            <Meta
                name="p:domain_verify"
                content="1228088838575c68d8e15366463bb836"
            />
            <Link rel="preconnect" href="https://images.prismic.io" />
            <Title>{meta.title}</Title>
            <Meta name="title" content={meta.title} />
            <Meta name="description" content={meta.description} />
            <Meta property="og:type" content="website" />
            <Meta
                property="og:url"
                content=""
            />
            <Meta property="og:title" content={meta.title} />
            <Meta
                property="og:description"
                content={meta.description}
            />
            <Meta property="og:image" content={meta.image} />
            <Meta
                property="twitter:card"
                content="summary_large_image"
            />
            <Meta
                property="twitter:url"
                content=""
            />
            <Meta property="twitter:title" content={meta.title} />
            <Meta
                property="twitter:description"
                content={meta.description}
            />
            <Meta property="twitter:image" content={meta.imagge} />
            {headerChildren}
        </header>
        <main className="Layout__content">{children}</main>
        <Footer data={footerInfo} />
    </div>
</LayoutContainer>
```

When I view the page source for the dynamic pages I don't see the metatags I'm trying to generate. I only see this:

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#663399"/><meta name="generator" content="Gatsby 2.21.1"/>
```

and then some CSS code, etc. None of the metatags I wanted.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler than what you have tried. Just use `<SEO>` component (built-in) in any [Gatsby starter](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/blob/master/src/components/seo.js) like:

```
<Layout>
<SEO description={meta.description} 
     title={`${post.post_title[0].text} | Not Just a Box Events`} 
     image={blog.page_hero_image.url} />
    {children}
</Layout>
```

*Note that you may need to adapt the component to receive the `image` as a `prop`.*

This approach will work for both (static and dynamic) pages. SSR shouldn't affect SEO.

Comment: In essence that SEO component still uses react-helmet. I still don't understand why even if i used react-helmet it's not working

Comment: Why do you mean by "is not working"? Is your `SEO` component empty? How are you using it?